# Creating subset of borders in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, layers, select, borders

I am using the VG250 dataset from http://www.geodatenzentrum.de. I am trying to create a new layer that contains only the borders of four federal states that are next to each other.

[image]

I want the new layer to basically only contain the blue line. (Sorry for the crude drawing)

My goal is to then run a buffer around these borders and then create a selection of municipalities that lie in the buffer area.

One challenge was that the borders of one federal state were stored as one feature.

What I ended up doing is using the 'split feature' tool to split the border lines. Then I deleted the superfluous borders.

After some trial and error, I think another option to get the exact borders would be to create a layer containing the whole border of each federal state and then using the 'intersection' function to extract the borders of interest.

However, this takes quite some time to do manually, so I still seek a simpler suggestion.

Comment: Does it have to be automated or would simply doing it manually be an option?

Comment: What have you tried? I think the easiest way for such a small number of intersections (assuming they're all topologically sound) would be to convert polygons to lines and then manually select them.

Comment: @bugmenot123 By doing it manually do you mean manually "draw" a line and add vertices etc.? Ideally, I would like to do it automated so that I just have to use a built in tool, a plugin or code.

Comment: @scabecks I have coverted the polygons to lines, but how can I go about selecting them? For my purpose it would perfectly suffice if I could select the borders in such a way that it returns the line between specified border intersections.

Comment: Once converted to lines you should be able to select the individual segments (the touching borders) using the select feature tool. Just hold down shift while doing so.

Comment: if you don't mind using a bit of code [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/236968/55203) might work - it gets duplicate line segments (even those overlaid which go in opposite directions)